# pre-processing to improve feature detector before tracking - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction, threshold

I am trying to make tracking for soccer player, I need to detect features from this player and then estimate the distance difference of these pixels over number of frames.

first I have to detect the main features of the player and then match them to those in the next frames, then calculate the distance difference.

My problem, there is no good feature detector at MATLAB to my case, these sample from the existing detectors:

**FAST**

[image]

**Harris**

[image]

**SURF**

[image]

**Q: I see that I can improve feature detector by doing preprocessing such like:
adaptive thresholding, opening & closing and sharping to highlight the player edges.
I have do the first one to make adaptive threshloding, and then make the feature detector for the output logical image, such like the following**

**After adaptive thresholding Harris, for logical image**

[image]

I tried to make the feature detector on gray image after thresholding but I couldn't change logical image to gray image.

Also any suggestion or alternative approach to do?

Comment: Well, this is by far a complex problem, as shown... What i would try to do at this stage is to detect 'Soccer Player Positions' detection on the field, instead of 'Soccer Player Features Positions' on an image. The first problem is truly simple and works for individual players, for the ball, distinguish players, shows the field lines, etc. The second, which you are trying to tackle, is really misleading, unclear, absolute, and less useful...

Comment: I can see some points are correctly detected, as an example points around number 9. IMO, you can do two things. First, select point pairs within a predefined gradient value, that way you can remove strange matches. Second, try to select only several best matches.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the blurriness it's going to be quite hard for you to get any more information out of these images.

Is this video? Why don't you use a person detector with a Kalmann filter instead? Then when you have the center of the person estimated you can use that to easily calculate the distance. 
(Sorry for posting as an answer, I don't have enough reputation yet).